# VIDIOC_DQBUF hangs on camera disconnection

Tags: c++, multithreading, v4l2

My application is using v4l2 running in a separate thread. If a camera gets disconnected then the user is given an appropriate message before terminating the thread cleanly. This works in the vast majority of cases. However, if the execution is inside the VIDIOC_DQBUF ioctl when the camera is disconnected then the ioctl doesn't return causing the entire thread to lock up.

My system is as follows:

- Linux Kernel: 4.12.0
- OS:  Fedora 25
- Compiler: gcc-7.1

The following is a simplified example of the problem function.

```
// Get Raw Buffer from the camera
void v4l2_Processor::get_Raw_Frame(void* buffer)
{
struct v4l2_buffer buf;
memset(&buf, 0, sizeof (buf));

buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

// Grab next frame
if (ioctl(m_FD, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf) < 0)
{   // If the camera becomes disconnected when the execution is
    // in the above ioctl, then the ioctl never returns.

    std::cerr << "Error in DQBUF\n";
}

// Queue for next frame
if (ioctl(m_FD, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf) < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Error in QBUF\n";
}

memcpy(buffer, m_Buffers[buf.index].buff, 
   m_Buffers[buf.index].buf_length);
}
```

Can anybody shed any light on why this ioctl locks up and what I might do to solve this problem?

I appreciate any help offered.

Amanda

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having the same issue. However, my entire thread doesn't lock up. The ioctl times out (15s) but thats way too long.

Is there a what to query V4L2 (that wont hang) if video is streaming? or at least change the ioctl timeout ?

UPDATE:

@Amanda you can change the timeout of the dequeue in the v4l2_capture driver source & rebuild the kernel/kernel module
modify the timeout in the dqueue function:

```
if (!wait_event_interruptible_timeout(cam->enc_queue,
                                      cam->enc_counter != 0,
                                      50 * HZ)) // Modify this constant
```

Best of luck!